# Azure Function: IoT Hub C2D message (promise of enqueue) far too slow

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I'm using a NodeJs Azure Function to send Cloud-To-Device (C2D) messages by using an IoT Hub service client. These messages are then read by a MQTT client subscribing to the topic filter devices/[device-name]/messages/devicebound/#

Below is some of the index.js code. hashedMessageArray is a very simple JSON with a few hashed fields and I'm trying to always use the async/await pattern as per Azure best practices.

```
// Libraries
const Client = require('azure-iothub').Client;
const Message = require('azure-iot-common').Message;

// Source and Target
const serviceClient = Client.fromConnectionString(process.env.SERVICE_IOT_HUB_CONNECTION_STRING);
const targetDevice = process.env.TARGET_DEVICE_ID;

// Open connection
await serviceClient.open();


// C2D Message
const message = new Message(JSON.stringify(hashedMessageArray));
message.ack = 'full';
message.messageId = Crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

// Send
context.log('Sending message: ' + message.getData());
await serviceClient.send(targetDevice, message);
context.log('Sent message: ' + message.getData());
```

Between the two context.log() calls, there's an average of **14 seconds of delay**: this is the time required by the awaited promise before confirming the enqueing of the message.

How is it possible and what can be done to achieve near-real-time communication?

Comment: Is this an intermittent issue? There could be a network latency that might be causing the delay. May I also know the size of the telemetry data you are trying to push. Did you try to test the code from your local machine with the same telemetry and notice any difference in the code performance?

Comment: It's not an intermittent issue and the size of the pushed telemetry data is around 500 bytes. I tried locally a stripped down version of the code and it actually is very performant, almost real time. Somehow, it seems the issue is related to being in an Azure Functions execution context.

Answer (score 0):

> The delay is due to the time it takes for the IoT Hub service to enqueue the message and send it to the device.

You can optimize it with the below steps:

Using a singleton instance of the IoT Hub service client to avoid the overhead of creating a new client for each function invocation.

Using the `sendBatch method` to send multiple messages in a single call to reduce the number of round trips to the IoT Hub service.

Using the `sendEventBatch method` to send multiple messages to multiple devices in a single call to further reduce the number of round trips.

Using the `sendEvent method` to send messages asynchronously without waiting for a response from the IoT Hub service.

And also, by using a different protocol, such as `AMQP` helps to improve the performance of `IoT Hub communication`.

able to send messages to IOT device without any delay.

Code in `Node JS` to receive messages from device.

```
const  client = Client.fromConnectionString(connString, Mqtt);
client.open((err) => {if (err) {
console.error('Error while connecting IoT Hub:', err);
} 
else 
{
console.log('Connection opened');
deviceclient.on('message', (msg) => {
console.log('Received message from device:', msg.getData().toString())
;});}});
```

[image]

Code in `Node JS` to send messages to device.

```
const client = Client.fromConnectionString(connString, Mqtt);  
client.open((err) => {  
if (err) {  
console.error('Error while openining IoT Hub :', err);  
} else {  
console.log('IoT Hub connection opened');  

const message = new Message(JSON.stringify({  
data: 'Hello from the cloud!'  
}));  
console.log('Sending message:', message.getData());  
client.sendEvent(message, (err, res) => {  
if (err) 
{  
console.error('Error sending message:', err);  
} 
else 
{  
console.log('Message sent to IoT device with status:', res.constructor.name);  
}  
client.close(); }); }});
```

[image]

For more information refer to the [MSDoc.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements?tabs=net-standard-sdk-2)

Comment: My question is about the SERVICE client library, not the DEVICE client library. The sendEvent and the sendBatch methods do not even exist for this type of client and by default the protocol is already AMQP: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-iothub/client?view=azure-node-latest

Comment: "Using a singleton instance of the IoT Hub service client to avoid the overhead of creating a new client for each function invocation"  --> This is another issue, but could help in the performance optimization. How could it be implemented in Azure Functions?

Comment: To use a singleton instance of the IoT Hub service client in Azure Functions, you can create a static instance of the client in your function code and reuse it across function invocations. Check this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-function-twin-getstarted#use-a-singleton-instance-of-the-iot-hub-service-client-in-azure-functions).